# Converting a JPEG image to less colours via PHP

Tags: php, gd

I need to decrease the amount of colours in an image, as right now the letters in my image have many shades of black, I'd need to turn all dark colours into actual black and so on, so I'm guessing decreasing the amount of colours, I'm using the following code(it crops the picture and is supposed to decrease the number of colours) however it seems to bring bak exactly same image?

```
<?
$filename = 'img1.jpg';

list($current_width, $current_height) = getimagesize($filename);

$C = 8;
$A = 5;
$B = 52;
$D = 11;

// Resample the image
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($B, $D);
imagetruecolortopalette($canvas, false, 20); // Supposed to only have 20 colours?? 
$current_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopy($canvas, $current_image, 0, 0, $C, $A, $B, $D);

imagejpeg($canvas, "img2.jpg", 100);
echo "<img src='img2.jpg'/>";
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

JPEG is not a palette-based format, so the results of calling `imagetruecolortopalette` aren't well-defined. Generate output in an image format that supports palette colors, like PNG or GIF.

(Also, if you're just working with a static image, why don't you just fix the image in an editor?)

Comment: Oh yeah, should convert it to gif then do this.. silly me, and to answer your question, because I'm building a captcha solver for fun (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282919/solving-captcha-with-php-personal-challange) 4am, not the freshest head

Answer (score 0):

Awhile ago I wrote a function to do this.

```
function alpha($image,$r=0,$g=0,$b=0){
$width=imagesx($image);
$height=imagesy($image);
$aw=0;
$ah=0;
for(;;){
if ($aw==$width) {$aw=0; $ah++;}
if ($ah==$height) break;
$rgb = imagecolorat($image, $aw, $ah);
$colors = imagecolorsforindex($image, $rgb);
$ar = $colors['red'];
$ag = $colors['green'];
$ab = $colors['blue'];
$ar+=$r;
$ag+=$g;
$ab+=$b;
if ($ar>255) $ar=255;
if ($ag>255) $ag=255;
if ($ab>255) $ab=255;
if ($ar<0) $ar=0;
if ($ag<0) $ag=0;
if ($ab<0) $ab=0;
$newcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, $ar, $ag, $ab);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 55, 0);
imagesetpixel ($image , $aw , $ah , $newcolor );
$aw++;
}//end loop
return $image;}
```

You can adjust the RGB of the whole image with positive or negative int's

for example, to remove red colors

```
alpha($image,-225,0,0);
```

Note that the function name: alpha, actually has nothing to do with the alpha channel. It can make an image appear like it has the alpha channel effect.