# How to get number from captcha with php

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I want to get number from captcha on http://control.ozsub.com/Account/Login.aspx

It looks like using CURL in php to get the input captcha image and get the result number on the image

Here's a picture of the captcha:
[captcha image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vNO9.png)

Can anyone provide a solution.
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving captcha with PHP? Personal challenge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282919/solving-captcha-with-php-personal-challenge)

Answer (score 0):

hahaha since there are less than 10,000 valid answers and minor mutation, you can probably create an imagemagick compare based approach that saves each new captcha that is too unlike every other captcha saved so far, let that run for a day and you should have one of all unique answers, then just solve those 9999 captchas manually once, and from there on solve them by cross-referencing the captcha with the known images with imagmagick compare, the image which is most similar to one of the known-solved images is your answer :P

this ofc requires that you're willing to solve 9999 of those captchas once manually. check https://imagemagick.org/script/compare.php

fwiw that's a really weak home-made captcha